# The print of string constant is always attached with 'b' inTensorFlow

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow

Durng the test of TensorFlow r0.12(CPU) installed on Windows 10, I found that the printed string contant is always with an 'b' in the end. The print of python is normal. I cannot figure out the reason so came here for help. The code is as follows:

```
>>>import tensorflow as tf
>>>hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
>>>sess = tf.Session()
>>>print(sess.run(hello))
b'Hello, TensorFlow!'
```

Comment: The `b` prefix is to indicate byte strings rather than unicode strings. The default depends on your python version: python2 `str` is bytes, but python3 `str` is unicode.

Comment: Briefly: it's a `bytes` object.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use `sess.run(hello).decode()` because it is a bytestring. `decode` method will return the string.

Your print statement must look like

```
print(sess.run(hello).decode())
```

Comment: The  `Tensor` object has no attribute `decode`, so did you mean `print(sess.run(hello).decode())`?  This worked for me.

Comment: why isn't this mentioned on [Validate your tensorflow installation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows#validate_your_installation)!? (I use 3.6.2 which should use unicode `str`)

Comment: Yeah it's always a bummer when you're trying something new, and things don't go the way. Even little warnings can be really annoying. I hope they would fix that on the website.

Comment: 2018 and still not fixed on website. Thanks @kermis