# Tensorflow install on Mac

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow

I am having a difficult time getting tensorflow to install on a MacBook Pro.

Initially, I tried `pip3.8 install tensorflow` in my virtual environment. It installed but gives the following error when I try to use it:

> ```
>     This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library  (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
> To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
> ```

I get that this is a warning, but I think it's a serious warning that I am going to have performance issues with any non-trivial work.

Based on this post ([Tensorflow on MacOS: Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51681727/tensorflow-on-macos-your-cpu-supports-instructions-that-this-tensorflow-binary)), I uninstalled tensorflow and followed the steps. After I installed Bazel, using homebrew, I got an error when I ran `./configure`:

> Please downgrade your Bazel installation to version 0.26.1.

According to this: (https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases) the oldest version is 3.2. I had 3.7 installed. So I uninstalled Bazel using homebrew. This felt like a dead end even though compiling from the source seems like the correct way to go. That version it's asking for is not even remotely close to a current version. I think the message is not telling me what I need to know.

Next I tried using pip to install the version recommended by Tensorflow.org. (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip.html)

```
pip3.8 install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-2.4.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_14_x86_64.whl
```

This successfully installed as well, but gives me similar errors as my original install and fails the test recommended under the list of installations on the tensorflow.org page.

I *think* I'm making a novice mistake. Can anyone assist here?

Comment: It is not a serious warning, you are completely overreacting to it.

Comment: I did a similar thing just now. Running `bazel --version` in the tensorflow directory now told me exactly how to install the older bazel executable that let me properly compile tensorflow. I was able to follow the site you linked after that. The only other thing that didn't work for me was, uninstalling protobuf wasn't necessary, so I had to `pip install protobuf` again before I was able to finish the compilation.

Answer (score 1):

It's not serious warning, you can either wait for macOS 12.0+ to have built-in [Apple Metal Acceleration](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/) or run [Intel optimized wheels](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-optimization-for-tensorflow-installation-guide.html) for macOS, but it support only TensorFlow 2.0