# How to print a plain text constant in tensorflow eager execution mode

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have initialized a constant in tensorflow:

```
hello = tf.constant('hello')
```

In normal mode, `print(sess.run(hello).decode())` outputs the plain text in a constant Tensor.

In eager execution mode however, the code above does not work.

How can I print the plain text in constant Tensor hello?

This question is NOT about [python b'str'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6269765/11074017) or [tf sess.run](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40904979/11074017)

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal `print( hello )` gives  'tf.Tensor(b'hello', shape=(), dtype=string)', I want just 'hello' part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert tensor to numpy array and then decode

```
print(hello.numpy().decode())
```