# Why b comes out in front of tensorflow output?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm a Tensorflow beginner.
I've tried to print Hello world using below Tensorflow 1.15.0 code.

```
import tensorflow as tf

h = tf.constant("Hello")
w = tf.constant(" World!")
hw = h + w

with tf.Session() as sess:
    ans = sess.run(hw)

    print(ans)
```

When I run the code using jupyter notebook, **b'Hello World!'** came out.

What I expected is only 'Hello World!". Why does the b come out in front of my output?

Many thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The b prefix indicates that it is a byte string and not unicode string. You can use tf.print() to print it properly

This question has already been answered here: [The print of string constant is always attached with 'b' inTensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40904979/the-print-of-string-constant-is-always-attached-with-b-intensorflow?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Comment: Thank you. It's helpful a lot.